# Grabbing certain data out of database

Tags: entity-framework

I am struggling grabbing some data out of my database

My database design is like this: I have a hotel that has a hotelchainid, a building that has a hotelid, a floor that has a buildingid and a room that has a floorid.

I'm trying to grab all the rooms from a certain hotel out of the database

Databasehandler.cs method:

```
        public static List<Room> GetAllRoomsByHotel(string hotelname)
        {
        HotelDbContext context = new HotelDbContext();

        var hotel = context.Hotels.Where(h => h.Name == hotelname).Single();
        var buildings = context.Buildings.Where(b => b.Hotel.HotelID == hotel.HotelID).ToList();
        var floors = context.Floors.Where(f => f.Building.BuildingID == buildings.BuildingID).ToList();
        var rooms = context.Rooms.Where(r => r.Floor.FloorID == floors.FloorID).ToList();

        return rooms;
        }
```

I was thinking about adding the found objects to a List and looping through that list to get the id's and comparing them afterwards but i'm not sure how to accomplish that and if that would work.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: That's exactly what navigation properties are for. (`Hotel.Buildings`, etc.) Do you have those? When in doubt, please show (the essential parts of) your class model.

Comment: @GertArnold I don't have navigation properties but heard from them before, If I create these properties will it be easier to manage this type of logic? This is how my models look like: http://pastebin.com/1iHtV8Eu (the essential parts)

Comment: Well, you have navigation properties from child to parent (`Building.Hotel` etc.). It should be possible to create parent-child navigation properties too (`public virtual ICollection<building>Buildings { get; set; }` in `Hotel`, etc.), simply by adding them to your classes. EF seems to be able to resolve everything by naming conventions.

Comment: @GertArnold Thank you, I can get the buildings inside an ICollection now by calling var buildings = hotel.Buildings; but I am not quite sure how I can get all the floors from all the buildings in order to get all the rooms from all the floors, Would I have to loop through this ICollection or is there a easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got all navigation properties in place, you can achieve what you want by

```
context.Hotels.Where(h => h.Name == hotelname)
              .SelectMany(h => h.Buildings)
              .SelectMany(b => b.Floors)
              .SelectMany(f => f.Rooms)
```

Which will give you a collection of rooms belonging to the hotel specified by `hotelname`.

Often, esp. with `SelectMany`, query syntax is easier ...

```
from h in context.Hotels where h.Name == hotelName
from b in h.Buildings
from f in b.Floors
from r in f.Rooms
select new
{
    Hotel = h.Name,
    Building = b.Name,
    Floor = f.Number,
    Room = r.Number
}
```

... because, as you see, it's easier to include parent data in the end result if that's desired.

Comment: Thanks alot for the assistance, that worked! The code is indeed alot better when using navigation properties